# How can I merge these two SPF records?

Tags: networking, dns, spf

I'd been trying to merge these two into one on the TXT records tab but I get all kinds of errors:

```
v=spf1 include:zoho.com ~all
v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `include` but then `~all` and `?all` are not the same so you will have to choose between them.

Hence, either one of these:

- `v=spf1 include:zoho.com include:servers.mcsv.net ~all`
- `v=spf1 include:zoho.com include:servers.mcsv.net ?all`

See http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax for all detailed explanations (you will find explanations of the difference between `~` and `?`) and for example https://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-syntax-validator to test the syntax of what you want to use.

Comment: I’d recommend going with `~all`. `?all` is effectively the same as not having SPF at all.